# Check if a user is authenticated in controller

Tags: symfony, security, authentication

There are many code snippets how to check if authenticated user is authorized to request a resource. But i cannot find a example to check if the user is authenticated at all.

I've got a kernel request listener, in which i'm trying to check if a user is authenticated, using this code:

```
if (TRUE === $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) 
{
    //doing stuff
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException in classes.php line 5307:
The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.
```

I guess, this is because the user is not logged in at all, and therefore doesn't have any authentication token.

So my question is: how do i, in a symfony controller, check if a user is authenticated before i check if he is authorized?

Comment: Are you sure that you need to check for it manually? Symfony Security can do it for you by denying access to certain routes for unauthorized users.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it like that :

```
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security.html#checking-to-see-if-a-user-is-logged-in-is-authenticated-fully), you can use `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` or `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`:

```
if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
    throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
}

// do stuff
```